# How to SQL SUM with condition

Tags: sql, sum

I have a transaction table and want to calculate based on the type of transaction. How to?

Table:

```
id | amount | type
--------------------
01 | 230    | IncomingTransfer
02 | 100    | OutcomingTransfer
03 | 20     | IncomingTransfer
```

Logic:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
IF IncomingTransfer
    + 230
    + 20
ELSE IF OutcomingTransfer
    - 100

Total amount: +150
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AS simple as my **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43aed/1)** shows:

```
select
sum(CASE WHEN type = 'IncomingTransfer' THEN amount ELSE -amount END) as totalsum
from t;
```

Comment: Brilliant...didn't realise you could do that.

Comment: yes, very simple and useful .. actually I think it was introduced back in the SQL-92 standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM (
   SELECT CASE WHEN type='IncomingTransfer'
      THEN +amount
      ELSE -amount
      END as amount
   FROM MyTable
) as data
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
    SELECT Amount = SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'OutcomingTransfer' then (Amount*-1) 
                    ELSE Amount END)
    FROM <Table>
    GROUP BY <Grouping Field>
```

Comment: No need for the GROUP BY - using that just breaks things in this case

Comment: You're right. Although I wasn't sure if there were additional fields to group by in this particular question (StoreId, Date, etc.) or if an overall sum was desired - So to be thorough I included the Group By.