# Getting sum of column which mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Getting sum of column mysql
I am trying to do

```
bid amount  |color
100         | Red
200         | Blue
200         | Red
 10         | Blue
100         | Red
```

Get sum of bid amount by color
For red color sum for blue color sum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL GROUP BY and SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174862/sql-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: You can check this as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663232/how-to-sql-sum-with-condition. You can modify the query as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select color, sum(bid_amount) total_bid_amount
from mytable
group by color
```